# "No DbContext was found in assembly" error when trying to add migrations in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I am making a `C# MVC` application using `Entity Framework 6.2.0` Everything was going fine until today when I tried to do some migrations.

I had no problem with migrating a week ago but I have no idea what might have caused the error in the package manager:

> No DbContext was found in assembly 'Data'. Ensure that you're using
>   the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor
>   generic.

I tried reinstalling `Entity Framework` and made sure that the "Default project" is the right one. I already have a context file that worked properly.

This is my `GameContext.cs` code:

```
public class GameContext :DbContext
{
    public GameContext()
        :base ("name=GameContext")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Game> Game { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Account> Account { get; set; }
}
```

I need to find a way to fix this problem and manage to update my database.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: @MichaelBeuving MSSQL

Comment: Please check your connection string, it should be named GameContext, the error is usually thrown when the app cannot locate you dbContext (through the conn string)

Comment: @MichaelBeuving It is named that way. Any other ideas?

Comment: change "name=GameContext" to "GameContext" OR in the NuGet Package Manager Console, check if the "Default project" is the one your context is in and the one you want, if having multiple projects...

Answer (score 1):

You maybe need to select ProjectName.Data in project management console[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your assembly name when registering the service, you can find assembly name by going to project properties.

```
services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>
            (
                dbContextOptionsBuilder =>
                {

                    dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("yourConnection",
                        optionsSqlServer => { optionsSqlServer.MigrationsAssembly("ADD_YOUR_ASSEMBLY_NAME");});

                }
            );
```